# How do I subtract column(child_age) in data frame A from column(mother_age) in data frame B?

Tags: python

Please guys.
How do I compare the circle columns in data frame A with data frame B.
in dataframe A I have mother's Age and dataframe B i have child's age.
I want to get all those mothers data which have 10 years of difference with their childs. eg. (mother_age-child_age=10 year difference)
and off course mother have more then 1 child as show in pic circled with black lines.
-> Ignore editing and English

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqQSj.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This code will give you the names of the id's that satisfy the request.

```
mothers_names_list = []
for id in mothers.from_uniqe_id.unique():
    mother_age = mothers[mothers.from_uniqe_id == id].BB
    tmp = childs[(childs.from_uniqe_id == id) & ((mother_age - childs.BB) > 10)]
        if tmp.shape[0] > 0: # Say if it have min of 1 child 
            mothers_names_list.append(tmp.from_uniqe_id)
```

Comment: tmp = childs[(childs.from_uniqe_id == id) & ((mother_age - childs.BB) > 10)] edited

Comment: it return empty list.
either if i change the condition the result is same

Comment: For this 2 data frames it works.

mothers  = pd.DataFrame({"from_uniqe_id": ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'BB': [40,40,30]})

childs  = pd.DataFrame({"from_uniqe_id": ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'BB': [4,34,3]})

the output:

[array(['a'], dtype=object), array(['c'], dtype=object)]